# Text trimming in textbox control UWP

Tags: uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP app. I have tried to achieve text trimming on textbox control, but by default UWP textbox doesn't have the text trimming option. Need text trimming behaviour in textbox control

Comment: For uwp app, the TextBlock control contains a [TextTrimming property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.texttrimming?view=winrt-20348), however, the TextBox doesn’t support this property directly. Do you want to have the similar behavior like the TextBlock? You means the TextBox have the Text trimming effect when it lost the focus and the text width exceeds the TextBox width, right?

Comment: Why don’t you think about the [TextWrapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textwrapping?view=winrt-20348) property of TextBox, which is easier to reach. I suggest you could implement the wrapping effect instead the TextTrimming effect .